# Cannot show dynamically defined label for md-tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This is how my md-tabs blocks is defined:

```
<md-tabs class="stretch-height" flex md-selected="mbpSelectedIndex" md-border-bottommd-autoselect md-dynamic-height> 
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in mbpTabs" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)">
        <md-menu>
            <md-tab-label ng-right-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="mbpTable"  >{{tab.title}}</md-tab-label>
            <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item>
                    ...
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>  
        <md-tab-body>
            ...
        </md-tab-body> 
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Since when I introducted the `<md-menu>` tag, tab label placeholder `{{tab.table}}` isn't being replaced by Angular engine.

Controller for `{{tab.table}}` has been defined in the routeProvider of the module, as I'm developing a single-page application.

How can I replace the placeholder with the actual value of `tab.table`?

**EDIT**

I created a codepen to show the issue:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBQYyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a workaround: I used a div instead of md-tab-label